# JFrame Resizing in Desktop Application - NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I'm developing Java Desktop Application in NetBeans IDE. I want to show the login screen in  `JFrame` with small size. Then after getting login i want to extend `JFrame` to full screen with other panels.The problem is its showing once properly and from the next time it used to show the login screen with full screen.How can i avoid it? I'm placing different panels on the same frame.

While login

```
this.getFrame().setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
this.getFrame().setSize(360, 233);
this.getFrame().setResizable(false);
```

After login

`this.getFrame().setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

Comment: resize it when you show the login screen? Just to get this straight: You show a `JFrame` with a size of let's say `200x200` then you use that `JFrame` to display something else and resize it to fullscreen. Now when you show the login in the same `JFrame` you want it to resize back to `200x200`, right? If the `resize()` doesn't work maybe you should call `setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL)` before resizing

Comment: im using the main JFrame to show the login details tha im placing new jpanel which are of different size.Initially i designed my JFrame of login form size.

Answer (score 2):

Edit after chat;

> According to scenario; External desktop application hold, remember and
>   set frames size's to last settings. So inner panel must get external
>   main frame from desktop application and set size and location settings
>   after application runs after internal code runs.

There is no more things I can do about codes without having whole project :)

Previous answers;
For an alternative, you may use JDialog to login
else next time when you show login screen, reverse what you do when setting fullscreen.

Some code samples helps us to answer your question better.

Edit 2:
he next time before login screen did you use;

```
this.getFrame().setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
```

Edit 3: Code Sample

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.addMouseListener(frame);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(this.getExtendedState() == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH){
            this.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
        }
        else{
            this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this too.But after login i cant make the jframe to full screen.

Comment: I have no problem with above sample code in my answer. Every click on frame switches between maximized and normal size of frame

Comment: ya...But but im replacing the Jframes panel after login.Is it will be the proble?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5332/discussion-between-ykartal-and-sakthibalaji)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to show the login screen in `JFrame` with small size. Then after getting login I want to extend `JFrame` to full screen with other panels.

Show the frame at the full size, and make it the owner of a modal `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` that shows the login details.  If the login fails and the user chooses to cancel instead of try again, exit the app.

> If I design a new `JDialog` for login then how can I show it initially?

```
JFrame f = this.getFrame();
JDialog loginDialog = new JDialog(f,"Login",true);
loginDialog.add(loginPanel);  
loginDialog.pack();
f.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
f.setVisible(true);
loginDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
loginDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: As I said, Jdialog is more useful for this case.

Comment: Im developing in NetBeans Java Desktop Application.If ill design a new JDialog for login then how can can i show it initially.

Comment: If login user name and password is ok.Then how can i make the main frame visible from that login panel?

Answer (score 1):

Put in your constructor, after the initComponent() function a simple piece's code

```
initComponents();/*Function automated*/
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700,400).getSize());
setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);/*To see your application starts maximized!*/
```